# A kids' story collection in which one of the stories is about a hen who eats with a pair of fork and knife and lays square eggs

Tags: story-identification

I first read this collection about 10 or 15 years ago. It was a picture book (and a translation). I can remember some of the stories, but neither the title nor the author(s):

- An owl decides to wake in the morning and sleep at night, as he considers the habit attributed to his kind by other animals to be a stereotype. His neighbor's son, a boar, imitates him and starts going out to play at night. The owl has to spend a night searching for the kid, which eventually leads him to return to his original way of sleeping.
- An oddball of a hen, who eats with a pair of fork and knife, has the leisure of chasing her owners' poor cat and drinks milk directly from the cows' breasts, suddenly finds out that all the eggs she lay are cubes. The hen tries to avoid her owners out of shame, but in the end they praise her for the stackability of the eggs. They even order other hens to follow her way of life so that they too can lay square eggs.
- A cow believes that cows who simply produce milk are too ordinary. Instead, she eats lemon to make lemonade, which creates a massive business for her owner. As the trend of cows making lemonade gradually becomes the norm, she switches to eating strawberries and attracts even more customers. This repeats for a few times until she finds her true happiness in producing milk to nourish a calf.
- A rabbit and a wolf collaborate to make a carrot farm. The carrots they grow are so good that the wolf's entire family switch to eating carrots instead of meat.
- A fox, widely known to be dumb, decides to go on a hunt. He manages to catch a boar boy, who tricks him into playing hide-and-seek and then escapes for good. After that, he makes his way into a chicken coop, but leaves when told that from Monday til Sunday foxes are not allowed to visit the coop. He keeps telling himself that "next time I'll be smarter" but he never does, and at the end of the day he once again settles for his usual oat porridge.

Google doesn't help much, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! Were there any science fictional or fantastical elements to this story?

Comment: @fez Does talking animals count as fantasy?

Comment: As per our [meta consensus](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117) talking animals aren't really fantasy if they exist normally in that universe. This is a possible on-topic question over on [Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) though

Comment: I suppose though, one could make an argument that a cow that can make lemonade and then switches to strawberry (milk I am assuming?) is pretty fantastical! So it may be fine here too. Let's see what other users think

Comment: You write about a translation. From English to...? or from ... to English?

Comment: @Allerleirauh The book was in my native language. I'm not sure what language it was originally written in.